# Trouble Defining Methods to interact with ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, casting

I'm working on a school assignment where I need to access data from an ArrayList with some methods I've written.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String fileName = "USPopulation.txt";
    File fileReader = new File(fileName);
    ArrayList<Integer> populations = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(fileReader);

    while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
        populations.add(inputFile.nextInt());
    }

    System.out.println(populations.greatest());

    /**
 * Receives an ArrayList and returns the index of the value that has the
 * greatest increase from the previous value in the collection.
 * 
 * @param populations
 * @return greatestI
 */
    public static int greatest(ArrayList<Integer> populations) {

    int greatestDiff = 0;
    int greatestI = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < populations.size() - 1) {
        int tempDiff = populations.get(i + 1) - populations.get(i);
        if (tempDiff >= greatestDiff) {
            greatestDiff = tempDiff;
            greatestI = i + 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return greatestI;
    }
}
```

When I try and call my method, greatest, I'm met with the error

> The method greatest() is undefined for the type ArrayList.

I had thought that the defintion I needed was included in the parameter of my method, but apparently not.

The error messages and what I've found troubleshooting make it seem like I need to cast my `ArrayList populations` into a type the methods know how to deal with, but nothing I try seems to work.

Appreciate any help. Thanks to anyone who takes the time to help a noob out.
return smallestI;

Comment: You seem to be struggling with Java language basics. Please revisit any decent tutorial. That is not how you invoke a method.

Answer (score 0):

you should call it this way

```
greatest(populations);
```

the way you call it is like calling a function that's defined inside the Arraylist class which is not .. Your function is just a method that takes an arraylist as input

Answer (score 0):

There are two important things you need to understand here

> `populations` is an object of type ArrayList
>
> `greatest()` is a method which you have written in your own class. Its not part of the ArrayList Class

When you try to access `populations.greatest()` you are basically trying to run the method `greatest()` in the class `ArrayList`. So you should get an exception **"The method greatest() is undefined for the type ArrayList"**

Instead of that you need to call the method `greatest(arrayListObject)`, on an object of your own class or in a static way. Since you have already defined your method  as `static`, you can directly call it by passing the  object `populations` as an argument as below.

```
System.out.println(greatest(populations));
```

Answer (score 0):

/*call your greatest function with passing the parameter populations(arrayList) and also you missed closing bracket for main function.
*/

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

```
    String fileName = "USPopulation.txt";
    File fileReader = new File(fileName);
    ArrayList<Integer> populations = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(fileReader);

    while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
        populations.add(inputFile.nextInt());
    }

    System.out.println(greatest(populations));
}

/**
 * Receives an ArrayList and returns the index of the value that has the
 * greatest increase from the previous value in the collection.
 * 
 * @param populations
 * @return greatestI
 */
public static int greatest(ArrayList<Integer> populations) {

    int greatestDiff = 0;
    int greatestI = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < populations.size() - 1) {
        int tempDiff = populations.get(i + 1) - populations.get(i);
        if (tempDiff >= greatestDiff) {
            greatestDiff = tempDiff;
            greatestI = i + 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return greatestI;

}
```